# Redis check if value exists in Hash

Tags: python, hash, redis

I am using Redis for my application at the time user sign's up into the system using Redis Hash.

```
m = redis.StrictRedis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)

'''
Structure looks like this:
m.hmset(username, {'password':password, 'first_name':first_name, 'last_name':last_name, 'email_id':email_id, 'phone_no':phone_no})
'''

m.hmset(john, {'password':'abc', 'first_name':'John', 'last_name':'Doe', 'email_id':'john@gmail.com', 'phone_no':'1234567890'})
```

With this structure, I am able to validate that there are no 2 users with the same 'username' but I also want to validate if there are no 2 users with same email id and phone number. How to do that? Is there another structure that I should go with? I was trying to make Hashes of Hashes (as we can use in Java as nested HashMaps) but I think Redis doesn't supports that. So is there a way with which I can do this? This is what I tried:

```
n = redis.StrictRedis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)
o = redis.StrictRedis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)
o.hmset('1234567890', {'password':'abc', 'first_name':'John', 'last_name':'Doe'})
n.hmset('john@gmail.com', o)
```

I got the following error doing so:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 1870, in hmset 
for pair in iteritems(mapping):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/redis/_compat.py", line 15, in <lambda>
    iteritems = lambda x: x.iteritems()
AttributeError: 'StrictRedis' object has no attribute 'iteritems'
```

Comment: You can do this with redis, e.g. by keeping all emails in a set and using `SISMEMBER`, but it seems very strange to keep registration data in redis instead of a "real" database...

Comment: yeah I know, but I just wanted to built a small application to get use to Redis. Anyway, if I use Redis-Set, wouldn't that be extra usage of space? and wouldn't that make the application slow since Redis uses cache?

Comment: Yes, it will use extra space.  No, it will not be slow.  Hardly anything in redis is slow, and using the right data type for finding duplicates is probably going to speed things up.